# Configure Apache VirtualHosts with a Load Balancer

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost, load-balancing

I have two servers, private IPs, Apache 2.4. I am serving the same content in both servers and there is a load balancer in front of these servers.

Load balancer uses a public IP, and there is a domain (mycompany.com) associated with it.

However, the client bought a new domain and want to use the same servers to serve the new content.

As far as I understand I need to configure VirtualHosts. I've read the documentation regarding VirtualHosts and it seems to be a case for name-based virtual hosts.

But since the public IP for the hostname is associated with the balancer, I do not know how I should configure the private servers in order that they be able to know how to solve which content to serve.

Appreciate the guidance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apache does not need to resolve anything regarding DNS.

Just make sure each new virtualhost for the new domains have the appropiate "**ServerName**" entry reflecting that new domain, this way Apache HTTPD will know where to deliver the request with specified Host.

Briefly an example:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName firstdomain.example.com
#....
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName newdomain.example.com
#....
</VirtualHost>
```